# Npm - update and save both deps and depsDev in 1 command line?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, package.json

I want to update multiple npm dependecies and save them to the respective package.json dependency slot.

My package.json:

```
{
   "dependencies": {
     "gulp": "^3.0.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-eslint": "^2.8.0"
   }
}
```

So i want to run:

```
$ npm update gulp gulp-eslint
```

That's ok but how to save the newer versions both for gulp (dep) and gulp-eslint (devDep) respectively ?

I tried:

```
$ npm update gulp gulp-eslint --save
```

but gulp-eslint is devDependency actually must be saved there, how to do all this in 1 command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the official documentation for [npm-update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) and notice that there are different specifications according  to the npm version you are using.

From the command line you can do:

```
$ npm update --save --dev
```

Note: Use `sudo` if your are on Linux or Mac.

Comment: shouldn't sudo be used only for globals when you don't have fixed permissions? local modules should be updated without sudo maybe i am mistaking !?

Comment: Ubuntu is my OS and I always use `sudo` to handle npm packages installations

Comment: I use Lubuntu (a derivative of Ubuntu), and never use `sudo`. In some cases, it is needed for `--global` actions; but you should fix npm permissions in those cases. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: yes on mac never used sudo for local packages, sudo is for globals when you don't have permisisons or you don't have fixed them ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Yarn, which is a new package manager, with this command:

```
yarn upgrade
```

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade

Comment: This will be good if he wants all the packages to be updated not only few of them.

Comment: Even the ones that are not supposed to be updated (eg. not having the ^)?

Comment: Yes. I wasn't sure so I have just confirmed that by running simple test on my repository. Event packages with no `^` or `~` characters were updated.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you